# Django Public user profile + user's posts

Tags: django

I hope you're well. I'm beginning with Django.

I'd like to create - like facebook - a public profile. I've already created a **UserProfileUpdateView** with country, adresse, image, ...

When a user post something I'd like to have a link to his public profile (country, adresse, image, ... + posts):

```
class UserPostView(ListView):
    template_name = 'user_post.html'
    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'posts'

 def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(UserProfileView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['userprofile'] = UserProfile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
            return context


    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(user=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

A - I'd like to display the public profile link with username (which is unique) and not with a number. Does anyone has an idea about how I can solve this?

```
path('<int:pk>/',UserPostView.as_view(),name="user_posts"),
```

UserProfile (user app)

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    street = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=300)
    number_street = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=20)
    street_detail = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=300)
    town = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=60)
    zipcode = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=20)
    country = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=60)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True,default='user/user-128.png', upload_to='user/')
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False)
    
    def save(self, *args,**kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.user.username)
        super(UserProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        
        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        if img.height > 200 or img.width > 200:
            new_size = (200, 200)
            img.thumbnail(new_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
            
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Post (nutriscore app)

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    url_image = models.URLField(max_length=200, default=None)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE,related_name='blog_posts')
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = unique_slugify(self, slugify(self.title))
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)   

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: can you share the `Post` and `UserProfile` model. Is user a foreign key or another character field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user in the `Post` model is a foreign key and is `from django.contrib.auth.models.User`, then first scan the User table from `username` and then scan the UserProfile table using the id as follows

```
user = User.objects.filter(username=name).values()
user_id = user[0]['id'] # You get the id of the user
userprofile = UserProfile.objects.filter(user_id=userprofile).values() # Scan the UserProfile table using the id obtained above 
user_post = Post.objects.filter(user = user_id) # post by authenticated user
```

Comment: thank you for your help :) @login_required(login_url='/earlycooker/login')
def userpublicpostview(request, slug):
    user = User.objects.filter(username=name).values()
    user_id = user[0]['id'] # You get the id of the user
    userprofile = UserProfile.objects.filter(user_id=userprofile).values() # Scan the UserProfile table using the id obtained above 
    user_post = Post.objects.filter(author = user_id, slug=slug) # post by authenticated user 
    template = 'user_public_profile.html'
    return render(request, template, {'user_posts':user_posts,'userpublic': userpublic})

Comment: I got his issue :( name 'name' is not defined